Mod Valheim Unity Engine custom dropdown menu items text invisible
General Info
I'm working on a mod for the game Valheim. This game uses the Unity Engine version 2022.3.17. For this mod I'll need a 2D menu where the user can control all the options.
The Problem
Part of the menu requires me to create a dropdown control where the user can select a single item. Since I'm restricted to using C# code only, I'm developing this with pure code. The dropdown menu is fully functional. All items are added as expected. The menu opens as expected and the selected item can be changed as expected.
The problem is that the dropdown menu is much wider than the dropdown button itself, and the text on the menu items is not visible.
What have I tried to solve the issues?
To solve the width issue, I've tried forcing the width to be equal with the button:
templateRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(size.x, size.y * 4);
viewportRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(size.x, size.y * 4);
contentRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(size.x, size.y * 4);

To solve the issue with the invisible text, I've tried forcing a black text color, static size and making sure all objects are generated in the proper order:
Text itemLabel = itemLabelObject.AddComponent<Text>();
itemLabel.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
itemLabel.fontSize = 14;
itemLabel.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;
itemLabel.color = Color.black;

I've been adding debug statements all over the place to make sure all is working in proper order. The debug logs return:

[Info   : Unity Log] Dropdown Button created at position: (0.00, 0.00), size: (160.00, 30.00)
[Info   : Unity Log] Background image added to Dropdown Button
[Info   : Unity Log] Unity's Dropdown component added to Dropdown Button
[Info   : Unity Log] Caption text added to Dropdown Button
[Info   : Unity Log] Arrow image added to Dropdown Button
[Info   : Unity Log] Created Template for the Dropdown Menu
[Info   : Unity Log] Created a Viewport for the Dropdown Menu Template
[Info   : Unity Log] Content Container created and attached to the Viewport
[Info   : Unity Log] Created Item Template for items in the Dropdown Menu
[Info   : Unity Log] Item Label added to the Item Template
[Info   : Unity Log] Toggle component added to the Item Template
[Info   : Unity Log] Dropdown Template setup completed
[Info   : Unity Log] Options added to Dropdown Menu
[Info   : Unity Log] Dropdown setup finalized

Question
I'm completely at a loss as to why I can't fix these problems. So I'm hoping to get some help here to fix the width issue, but most importantly, make the item texts visible.
Full Code
internal static Dropdown CreateDropdown(Transform parentTransform, string name, Vector2 position, Vector2 size, List<string> options, UnityAction<int> onValueChanged)
{
    // Create the Dropdown Button
    GameObject dropdownObject = new GameObject(name);
    dropdownObject.transform.SetParent(parentTransform, false);
    RectTransform dropdownRectTransform = dropdownObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    dropdownRectTransform.anchoredPosition = position;
    dropdownRectTransform.sizeDelta = size;
    Debug.Log($"Dropdown Button created at position: {position}, size: {size}");

    // Add Image component for background
    Image backgroundImage = dropdownObject.AddComponent<Image>();
    backgroundImage.sprite = ModMenu.sprites["dropdownBackground"];
    backgroundImage.type = Image.Type.Sliced;
    Debug.Log("Background image added to Dropdown Button");

    // Add Dropdown component
    Dropdown dropdownComponent = dropdownObject.AddComponent<Dropdown>();
    Debug.Log("Unity's Dropdown component added to Dropdown Button");

    // Create the Caption Text
    GameObject labelCaption = new GameObject("Label");
    labelCaption.transform.SetParent(dropdownObject.transform, false);
    RectTransform labelRectTransform = labelCaption.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    labelRectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    labelRectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    labelRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0, 0);
    Text label = labelCaption.AddComponent<Text>();
    label.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
    label.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;
    label.color = Color.black;
    Debug.Log("Caption text added to Dropdown Button");


    // Create the Arrow Image
    GameObject arrowObject = new GameObject("Arrow");
    arrowObject.transform.SetParent(dropdownObject.transform, false);
    RectTransform arrowRectTransform = arrowObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    arrowRectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(1, 0.5f);
    arrowRectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 0.5f);
    arrowRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(20, 20);
    arrowRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(-10, 0);
    Image arrowImage = arrowObject.AddComponent<Image>();
    arrowImage.sprite = ModMenu.sprites["dropdownArrow"];
    arrowImage.color = Color.white;
    Debug.Log("Arrow image added to Dropdown Button");

    // Create the Template
    GameObject templateObject = new GameObject("Template");
    templateObject.transform.SetParent(dropdownObject.transform, false);
    RectTransform templateRectTransform = templateObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    templateRectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);
    templateRectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    templateRectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 1);
    templateRectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(0, -size.y);
    templateRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(size.x, size.y * 4);
    Image templateImage = templateObject.AddComponent<Image>();
    templateImage.sprite = ModMenu.sprites["dropdownBackground"];
    templateImage.type = Image.Type.Sliced;
    ScrollRect scrollRect = templateObject.AddComponent<ScrollRect>();
    scrollRect.horizontal = false;
    scrollRect.vertical = true;
    scrollRect.movementType = ScrollRect.MovementType.Clamped;
    Debug.Log("Created Template for the Dropdown Menu");

    // Create the Viewport
    GameObject viewportObject = new GameObject("Viewport");
    viewportObject.transform.SetParent(templateObject.transform, false);
    RectTransform viewportRectTransform = viewportObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    viewportRectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    viewportRectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    viewportRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(size.x, size.y * 4);
    Mask mask = viewportObject.AddComponent<Mask>();
    mask.showMaskGraphic = false;
    Image viewportImage = viewportObject.AddComponent<Image>();
    viewportImage.color = Color.clear;
    scrollRect.viewport = viewportRectTransform;
    Debug.Log("Created a Viewport for the Dropdown Menu Template");

    // Create the Content
    GameObject contentObject = new GameObject("Content");
    contentObject.transform.SetParent(viewportObject.transform, false);
    RectTransform contentRectTransform = contentObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    contentRectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);
    contentRectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    contentRectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 1);
    contentRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(size.x, size.y * 4);
    VerticalLayoutGroup layoutGroup = contentObject.AddComponent<VerticalLayoutGroup>();
    layoutGroup.childForceExpandHeight = false;
    scrollRect.content = contentRectTransform;
    Debug.Log("Content Container created and attached to the Viewport");

    // Create a template item for the Dropdown
    GameObject itemTemplateObject = new GameObject("Item");
    itemTemplateObject.transform.SetParent(contentRectTransform, false);
    RectTransform itemTemplateRectTransform = itemTemplateObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    itemTemplateRectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 1);
    itemTemplateRectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    itemTemplateRectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 1);
    itemTemplateRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0, 20);
    Image itemTemplateImage = itemTemplateObject.AddComponent<Image>();
    itemTemplateImage.color = new Color(1, 1, 1, 0.9f);
    Debug.Log("Created Item Template for items in the Dropdown Menu");

   
    // Create the Item's Label
    GameObject itemLabelObject = new GameObject("Item Label");
    itemLabelObject.transform.SetParent(itemTemplateObject.transform, false);
    RectTransform itemLabelRectTransform = itemLabelObject.AddComponent<RectTransform>();
    itemLabelRectTransform.anchorMin = new Vector2(0, 0);
    itemLabelRectTransform.anchorMax = new Vector2(1, 1);
    itemLabelRectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(0, 0);
    itemLabelRectTransform.pivot = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);
    Text itemLabel = itemLabelObject.AddComponent<Text>();
    itemLabel.font = Resources.GetBuiltinResource<Font>("Arial.ttf");
    itemLabel.fontSize = 14;
    itemLabel.alignment = TextAnchor.MiddleLeft;
    itemLabel.color = Color.black;
    Debug.Log("Item Label added to the Item Template");

    // Add the Toggle component to the item
    Toggle itemToggle = itemTemplateObject.AddComponent<Toggle>();
    itemToggle.targetGraphic = itemTemplateImage;
    itemToggle.graphic = itemTemplateImage;
    itemToggle.isOn = false;

    itemTemplateObject.AddComponent<LayoutElement>().preferredHeight = 20;
    Debug.Log("Toggle component added to the Item Template");

    // Set up the Dropdown Template
    dropdownComponent.template = templateRectTransform;
    dropdownComponent.captionText = label; // Assign the caption text component
    dropdownComponent.itemText = itemLabel; // Assign the item text component
    dropdownComponent.options.Clear();
    Debug.Log("Dropdown Template setup completed");

    // Add the options
    foreach (string option in options)
    {
        dropdownComponent.options.Add(new Dropdown.OptionData(option));
    }
    Debug.Log("Options added to Dropdown Menu");

    // Add listener for selection change
    if (onValueChanged != null)
    {
        dropdownComponent.onValueChanged.AddListener(onValueChanged);
    }

    // Set default value
    dropdownComponent.value = 0;
    dropdownComponent.RefreshShownValue();
    Debug.Log("Dropdown setup finalized");

    return dropdownComponent;
}

Call:
ModDropdown.CreateDropdown(ModMenu.containerTransforms["ESPContainer"], "Filter Monster", new Vector2(0, 0), new Vector2(160, 30), monsterOptions, index =>
{
    Debug.Log("Selected option: " + monsterOptions[index]);
});


